# Copy a folder without its hierarchy/tree

Tags: bash

If I have a variable `srcDir="~/a/b/c"` and would like to only copy the name `c` into a `$copyDir` via manipulating `$srcDir`, how would I go about doing this?

I've read parameter expansion and know how to store a directory, but it includes the entire folder tree. I just need to copy the folder name `c` and store it.

Comment: Stop vandalising your posts or you will be suspended.

Comment: @ozarka and stop vandalizing other peoples' posts as well

Comment: And please do *not* unaccept answers to the questions you've asked.

Answer (score 3):

You could use this:

```
srcDir=~/a/b/c

copyDir=${srcDir##*/}

echo $copyDir

c
```

More at http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html half-way down

Answer (score 3):

The `basename` command does this. You could use a command like this: `copyDir=$(basename $srcDir)`